# How to create scrollable "drop down" of check boxes in Java FX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, scrollbar

I am new to JavaFX and I'm trying to create a "dropdown list" of check items. I am trying to make the drop down scrollable. I can easily do this with a ComboBox (using setVisibleowCount(int)), but ComboBox only allows for 1 item to be chosen before closing the dialogue and doesn't seem to be the right object to use.

I am currently using a menu button with CheckMenuItems. ListView seems like it could be useful, but I'm not quite sure how to integrate that. If anyone can help that'd be great. Thanks.

[Current Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uvaL.png)

Comment: [`CheckComboBox`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/CheckComboBox.html) may be an option.

Comment: Use list view with the options inside of it, allowing users to select multiple items. It offers the same functionalities as a checkbox, you will just lose the drop down menu feature.

Comment: @Joe unfortunately, I'd need the dropdown or something that collapses so it is not cluttering the interface. Will look further into the options you and fabian presented though.

Comment: @fabian unfortunately, I cannot use CheckComboBox because I am using Java 11. From what I understand ControlsFx does exist yet for Java 11. Or maybe I am incorrect, do you know if there is a jar I can download for ControlsFX? I was having a hard time finding one.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot use a CheckComboBox I would see if an Accordion + TitledPane fits with what your doing.
Here is an example:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(new Label("Select Number of Checkboxes you feel like clicking"));

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            vBox.getChildren().add(new CheckBox("i:" + i));

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(vBox);
        //Easily changeable Max Height
        scrollPane.setMaxHeight(10);

        // Create TitledPane.
        TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane("Check Boxes", scrollPane);
        //Add to Accordion
        Accordion accordion = new Accordion(titledPane);
        //Add to root VBox
        root.getChildren().add(accordion);

        root.getChildren().add(new Label("Some Other Content"));

        stage  = new Stage();
        stage.setHeight(200);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

}
```